# Using the memoir class, how to baseline align without inserting space between paragraphs?

Tags: memoir

I'm using the memoir class and need to align the bottom of the pages in a page spread. By default, the memoir class does this by inserting spaces between paragraphs, which I don't want. So, I'm using the `\raggedbottom` command and inserting vertical spacing only where I want it.

I'm running into situations such as below where I want to add roughly half a line of vertical space, so I want to add just a tad of space above the two section titles on the right page.

[image]

I inserted the command `\vspace{\fill}` above both section titles, but it's only working for me if the space at the bottom of the page is more than a line or so. If it's small, like in the above example, I get this:

[image]

Can `\vspace{\fill}` solve this use case? If not, is there a better way?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{\fill}
\section{Section Five}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{\fill}
\section{Section Six}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Section Seven}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Here's an example of when `\vspace{\fill}` works great. I added the command `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` to line 11 and 23 of my MWE, which gives this:

[image]

Adding `\vspace{\fill}` above the section titles fixes things nicely, as shown below. So, I'd like to accomplish the same thing regardless of how small the space is at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: it seems it's not the minimum but maximum value you want to adjust, something like `\vspace{0pt plus 1\baselineskip}`

Comment: Pretty sure I mean minimum value. I'll update my OP to elaborate.

Comment: also you definitely don't want `\vspace*` use `\vspace` as you want to lose this space at a page break

Comment: in your image you are adding `\fill` space before each section which, as you show can grow arbitrarily large. also you are adding it in the wrong place before the `\penalty` added by `\section` so you are getting the fill space followed by a page break which is why the section 0.2 moved to the nect page leaving a large space

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for the tip not to use `\vspace*`. I updated my OP showing how `\vspace{\fill}` expands too large only when the bottom space is small.

Comment: yes exactly "too large"  so you want to stop vfill expanding that much so affect its maximum not minimum.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, apologies, my title was ambiguous. I changed it.

Comment: your title still doesn't match your need, the smallest allowable amount added by vfill is 0pt and skillmon's command is identical except the smallest allowable amount is 1cm, in what way does that not answer the question in the title?  I really can not guess what you are asking, I'm not just being argumentative for the sake of it:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks very much for the comment and the emoji :-) I too am perplexed why my question is so misunderstood. In the top figure of my OP, I want to lower the text on the right maybe 2mm to align the bottom of the text on the right with the text on the left. I can accomplish this by adding `\vspace{1mm}` above each section, but I want to add `\vspace{\fill}` instead and let LaTeX calculate the 1mm (or whatever the dimension is). Instead, it inserts much larger spacing, pushing text to the next page. My question is, can I correct this behavior?

Comment: The question in your previous comment is reasonable, but its unrelated to changing the smallest allowable space  of vfill from 0pt to some other value. vfill means add a space of at least 0pt that may be arbitrarily large. I can't read your title as anything else than change that 0pt, which is skillmon's answer.  Your actual example is unrelated to your title

Comment: if we ignore the title and try to address the flush bottom line, it seemed necessary to address the first page where the page is a line short because of the penalties, otherwise the end result even if you address the vfill is uneven bottom lines

Comment: the problem with the page with thesection titles is unrelated to th eamoint vfill stretches the problem is you have `<vspace> <allowbreeak> <section space><section heading> <nobreak> <section text>`  so if the page break happens at  the <allowbreak> penalty then you get the added `<vspace>` at the bottom of the page  you need to add the  spaces and penalties in a different order (and also stop the vspace being arbirarily large)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When my left page is a line short due to penalties, I do the same thing that publishing houses do---I shorten the page on the right to match. Or, I shorten a previous page to rejig the vertical length of the following page. Regarding `<vspace> <allowbreeak> <section space> <section heading> <nobreak> <section text>`, the allowbreak isn't triggered when I explicitly give `\vspace` a small value (e.g., 1mm). But, it is triggered if I give it `\fill`. Why can it not fill 1mm? Why does it expand beyond 1mm and push text to the following pages?

Comment: yes I mention that possibility on my answer, but you offer a three page example and none of the baselines align for different reasons, if you shorten all three by a line the problem goes. so you could ask how to balance that example but asking about the minimum size of vfill, which is 0pt, is completely unrelated

Comment: if you  use fill you are saying there is no penalty for making the space arbitrarily large, so you get large spaces. the minimum size is 0pt but not that relevant to your problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your comment above doesn't answer my question---`fill` doesn't give me "arbitrarily large" spaces when the space at the bottom of the page is as big as one or more lines, but when it's a fraction of a line, it does give me arbitrarily large spaces. Why? Why doesn't it insert a small space to fill the space? It seems like somewhere there is a setting to not insert a space smaller than 3pt or something to that effect. Can someone tell me if this is true and, if so, if there's a way to change this value to 0pt?

Comment: fill will grow without penalty to an arbitrary size to fill the available space, and has minimum size zero. that is what it _means_ . Other aspects of your example change the amount of space required on the page but your description of the problem in the title  is asking to change the minimum value of vfill which is 0pt and is unrelated to your real problem. I don't know how I can say this any differently as the conversation keeps cycling around this same point.

Comment: "It seems like somewhere there is a setting to not insert a space smaller than 3pt" No!!!! absolutely not, you are expecting an answer that simply is not there.  there is no setting remotely like that and that is not what is happening. The page is short and so needs filling, and so the vfill expands so you get big spaces.

Comment: By adding vfill you are saying there is no cost to having arbitrary large space so there is no cost to pushing the third section head on to the next page and then padding that page with big spaces. You get big spaces because you added them. If as I show in my answer you limit the amount the space can grow, there is a cost to pushing the section to the next page as the spaces would over-stretch, so the section stays on the page and is padded to the bottom which is the result you wanted.

Comment: The bottom of pages 2 and 3 of [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699382/272500) do not align. The bottom of page 3 is 8pts higher than the bottom of page 2.

Comment: that would be a bug then, I'll fix later, I was probably destracted by page 1:-)

Comment: I still do not understand why your explanations apply to the first example in my OP, but not the seccond? What is the difference between my two examples?

Comment: it's like line breaking, it's a least cost optimisation over the whole page balancing the costs from penalties and stretching space, so exactly what effect any particular change has on any given page isn't always obvious without tracing in full, but adding `\vfill` space which has 0pt natural size but will stretch to an arbitrary size with _no cost_  will make getting large white space mid page more likely than not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149299/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-buttonsrtoys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about this all wrong. As mentioned in my question, I want flush bottoms but no spaces between paragraphs. The default memoir class gives this output with the para spacing I don't want, like this:

[image]

So, I was using `\raggedbottom` to keep the paras together and then fixing the spacing between. Here's the same text with raggedbottom:

[image]

I now see I can use the default flush bottom spacing and get rid of the para spacing without using `\raggedbottom` by setting `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`, which works great but understandably give a big space above the section title:

[image]

Which can be reduced by shortening the both pages by one line with `\enlargethispage{-1\baselineskip}`:

[image]

My manuscript has lots of quoted text, sections, and figures, so lots of opportunities to add spacing that's not between paras. I'm sure this won't suit everyone's needs, but I tested it on the first 100 pages of my manuscript and it's working great for me.

Here's the code for the above examples

```
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{lipsum}

% \raggedbottom

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\subsection{Subsection Two}

\enlargethispage{-1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Section Five}

\enlargethispage{-1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Section Six}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Section Seven}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this addresses your use case but is completely unrelated to the question in the title, which is answered by Skillmon's answer who showed a command that does what you ask for, a command like `\vfill` but with a different minimum length. So you should accept that answer to get this off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: None of the solutions fixed my MWE, including Skillmon's. My OP may have been poorly worded, but none of the solutions answered my question satisfactorily. I could certainly be wrong, but it appears that Skillmon and other's didn't bother to test their solutions on my MWE. If they did, they would have seen the problem I was encountering and addressed it in their answers.

Comment: Your MWE had nothing to do with the question in the title. Skillmon ignored the example and answered the question, I ignored the question and tried to answer the implied problem in the example (although that wasn't very clear). The best way to resolve it is for you to accept skillmon's answer here and if you still have issues open a new question. It's not Skillman's fault that you posted an unrelated example.  vfill is a space of minimum width 0pt and arbitrary stretch and you asked how to change the minimum width. Skillman showd a command with minimum width 1cm and arbitrary stretch.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point. I updated my OP title to align with my MWE and clarified my question. Should be GTG now.

Answer (score 3):

This answers the question "How to adjust the setting for the smallest allowable space inserted by `\vspace{\fill}`?" In the meantime it was made clear that this wasn't what was actually needed. The answer is kept for posterity.

Instead of `\vspace*{\fill}` you could use `\vspace*{1cm plus 1fill}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.I still got the section moved to the next page. I tried a smaller value `\vspace{0.1mm plus \fill}` but that seemed to just add the 0.1mm and nothing else.

Comment: this does what the OP asks for, but isn't want the OP wanted, see my comment under the question/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This answer didn't answer my OP. I updated my OP to clarify.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys it exactly answers the question in the title, changing the minimum value from 0pt to 1cm, but what you ask for does not address the problem you show in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowing the space to grow arbitrarily large so introducing the large gaps before the section

```
\vspace{0pt plus \baselineskip}
```

would give penalties for growing more than a baselineskip and produces this:

[image]

where you see the page with the section headings is more reasonable and does have the page flush to the bottom, however the first page is a line short due to the setting

```
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
```

which is always problematic.

On that page you either need to allow the page (and perhaps so the double spread) to be short, or give up on the 10000 penalties or adjust the linebreaking with `\looseness`  but in this text there is no easy paragraph to force to be a line longer.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

{\emergencystretch=1em
\looseness=1
\lipsum[1]


}

\lipsum[2-4]


\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[6-10]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{0pt plus \baselineskip}
\section{Section Five}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{0pt plus \baselineskip}
\section{Section Six}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Section Seven}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

is

[image]

which is not clearly an improvement

Comment: Since I'm only filling small spaces at the bottom of pages, I want to allow the space to grow arbitrarily large. I also do not want orphans or widows, which is why I'm using the penalties. I just want to shrink the smallest value that `\vspace{\fill}` adds. So, this answer doesn't answer my OP.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys the smallest space that vfill adds is 0pt, what do you want it to shrink 0pt to? (this answer balances the baselines of the three pages shown, not sure why it has a downvote.