# How to adjust the smallest allowable space inserted by \vfill and \vspace{\fill}?

Tags: memoir

I'm reposting this question because [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699378/how-to-adjust-the-setting-for-the-smallest-allowable-space-inserted-by-vspace) was ambiguous, so the responses didn't answer my question.

I want `\vspace{fill}` to fill maybe 3pts of vertical space, but it's inserting too much and pushing text to the next page. It works great for larger spaces, like `\baselineskip`, but not for small spaces.

I'm using the memoir class and need to align the bottom of the pages in a page spread. By default, the memoir class does this by inserting spaces between paragraphs, which I don't want. So, I'm using the `\raggedbottom` command and inserting vertical spacing only where I want it.

I'm running into situations such as below where I want to add roughly half a line of vertical space, so I want to add just a tad of space above the two section titles on the right page.

[image]

I inserted the command `\vspace{\fill}` above both section titles, but it's only working for me if the space at the bottom of the page is more than a line or so. If it's small, like in the above example, I get this:

[image]

I realize I can replace `\fill` with explicit values, but it's a big manuscript and I'd rather have LaTeX figure this out if possible.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{\fill}
\section{Section Five}
\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{\fill}
\section{Section Six}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Section Seven}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

Here's an example of when I have a larger space and `\vspace{\fill}` works great. I added the command `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` to line 11 and 23 of my MWE to create this example, which gives this:

[image]

Adding `\vspace{\fill}` above the section titles fixes things nicely, as shown below. So, I'd like to accomplish the same thing regardless of how small the space is at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: sorry that's not how the site works, if the answers do not help then just don't accept them and (in this case)  edit to clarify your question, don't simply repost the entire question.